# "Error: The type 'JSObject' can't be used as supertype." while deploying flutter app to vercel

Tags: flutter, web-applications, vercel

Getting Error: The type 'JSObject' can't be used as supertype. error but I havent used dart.js anywhere in my code and unable to deploy my app to vercel.

[image]

below is my pubspec:

```yaml
name: appname
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none'
version: 0.1.0

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.5 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  get: ^4.6.6
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.6.0
  http: ^1.2.0
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.1.0
  

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

assets:
  - .env
```

Comment: Can you include your pubspec?

Answer (score 21):

I had this same issue, not sure what packages caused the issue, but running a

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

moved quite a few packages forward for my project and fixed the issue.

I suspect the package makers I rely on have updated their transitive dependencies. Give that a try before doing any dependency overrides.

If it is still causing an issue, you can force transitive depencies forward with:

```
dependency_overrides:
  web: ^0.4.0
```

This was on the `stable` Flutter channel, no need to swap to `beta`

Comment: hey thanks,it worked for me. could you provide any resources on how this fixes the issue? why this is caused?

Answer (score 5):

For me, it was as simple as running

```bash
flutter pub add web:^0.5.0
```

My `web` dependency was stuck at 0.3.0 as a transitive dependency. The above command updates it to the latest version by turning it into a direct dependency.

Answer (score 2):

The update [0.4.0](https://pub.dev/packages/web/changelog#040) of `web` has already addressed the issues shown in the error. From the [changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/web/changelog#040):

> Remove `implements JSObject` from all types.

For example, the class definition for `ReadableStream` in 0.3.0 was:

```dart
class ReadableStream implements JSObject {
```

It is now has changed to:

```dart
class ReadableStream {
```

---

The [`http`](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package depends on the [`web`](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package. In the version 1.2.0 of `http`, it depends on `web` with [this version constraint](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/blob/master/pkgs/http/pubspec.yaml):

```yaml
web: '>=0.3.0 <0.5.0'
```

To fix the issue, simply depends the `web` package directly in your pubscpec. It is safe to use version 0.4.0 and above since it still meet the constraints shown above.

In your pubspec file:

```yaml
dependencies:
  web: ^0.4.0
```

Now another problem arises, the `flutter_test` package may not be compatible with these changes. If you're not using `flutter_test`, you can simply remove it from the `dev_dependencies`. If you're using it, you can try upgrading the Flutter SDK to the version that has `flutter_test` supports `web` ≥ 0.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

same for me.  running pub upgrade did the trick.  I think it has to do with some sort of forced dependency in the latest flutter version.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with the `flutter build web` and `flutter run`commands.
Like most of the people here said, it was due to the dependency with an older version of `web`.

Got solved by `flutter pub upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get pass this issue. Here's my steps:

Switch to beta channel

```
flutter channel beta
```

Upgrade SDK

```
flutter upgrade
```

Upgrade dependencies

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

Deploy to vercel and issue should go away

Looking forward on `web: ^0.4.2` support in #flutter stable channel

Thanks @Dhafin Rayhan

Hope it helps

Comment: is there a way to integrate Vercel Environmental variable with flutter app